# How can I store a type that conforms to a protocol to be used later in an object?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, closures, protocols

I'd like to make a controller that can store a type and later create an object of that type. However, I'm getting a few compiler errors as noted below:

```
class Test:Codable {
    let str : String
    let x : Int
    let y : Int
}
class TestController: UIViewController {
    let type : Decodable
    init <T>(type: T) where T:Decodable {
        self.type = type
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func doSomething() {
        let x = type.init() // Static member 'init' cannot be used on instance of type 'Decodable'
    }
}
let controller = TestController(type: Test.self) // Initializer 'init(type:)' requires that 'Test.Type' conform to 'Decodable'
```

Is it only possible to do this by writing doSomething as a closure that is passed to init instead of the type?

Comment: This example is strange because you require `T` to be `Decodable`, but then expect `T` to have an empty `init()`. Either is possible (and both are possible), but which one do you actually need? `Decodable` promises that the type can be decoded. It doesn't promise it can be trivially (with no parameters) constructed. Once you've constructed `x`, what do you plan to do with it? There are no methods available on `x` according to your requirements.

Comment: This is simplified from what I'm actually trying to do. I don't need an empty init for x - I just need to be able to actually use type to initialize it. The problem is the last line. I can't seem to pass in a type that conforms to Decodable.

Comment: That's a completely separate issue (you're passing a type, but requiring an instance; you need `T.Type` in the signature). But the real solution depends on what you're actually going to do with this. Something that's just "Decodable" isn't useful. You're going to almost certainly get a different error (maybe 'does not conform to expected type "Decoder"') as soon as you try to use it.

Comment: I mean, the super short-version is to change your init to `init <T>(type: T.Type) where T:Decodable`, and your property to `let type: Decodable.Type`. But I'm really certain that's not actually going to work when you try to use it, so it depends on what you want to do with it.